# Does mv across filesystems flush the destination filesystem cache between copy and delete?

Tags: linux, mv, posix, coreutils, integrity

`mv` is implemented as a simple [`rename()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/rename.html) whenever possible, falling back to copy-then-delete whenever renaming doesn't work. In practice ([but not in theory](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/3a1c328cd55f427a74f16cda8513bedb7c153fd8/src/mv.c#L192-L202)), these two cases correspond to source and destination being on the same or on different filesystems, respectively.

**My question:** Does `mv`, as defined by the POSIX standard and implemented as part of the GNU coreutils, make any guarantee that in the latter case (i.e. rename not possible, fall back to copy-then-delete), filesystem caches are flushed (in the sense of [`sync`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync)) between the copy and delete operation so that disconnecting the destination filesystem at just the right moment won't lead to data loss?

**What I've found so far:** The [POSIX spec for `mv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) says that

> termination at any point shall leave either source_file or the destination path complete

which would suggest "yes", but then I'm not sure whether disconnecting a filesystem would be classed as simple "termination" or not, whether such statements in general only apply to the "surface" filesystem state, and so on.

There is a [Hacker News comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11804364) answering "no" but not citing any sources.

Maybe the question is actually ill-defined because [POSIX `sync()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/sync.html) does not even guarantee *completion* of the flush, only triggering it, so there is no way to implement a "completely safe" copy-then-delete across filesystems anyway?

I tried to find out how it's actually implemented in [GNU coreutils' `mv`'s source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/3a1c328cd55f427a74f16cda8513bedb7c153fd8/src/mv.c#L153), but before I waste any more time on this and in the interest of anyone else with the same question, I thought I'd ask here, too.

Comment: I think you need to make a difference between "on storage medium" and "userland visible"; sync flushes in-kernel caches to disk. However, the moment some write operation is in that cache, a read operation would already yield the cached value. So the question really is whether the copy operation is userland-wise done before the unlink happens

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's what I was trying to get at with "surface filesystem state", I just didn't know the correct terminology. If that sentence in the standard only applies to the userland-visible state, I guess the answer to my question would be "no". I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence - userland-wise the copy is definitely completed before the unlink happens. The cache flush question is the only ambiguous part.

Comment: `mv` doesn't flush anything when it's copying data. `sync` at least in Linux does indeed flush data, only there's no way of knowing when it completes - it only asks the kernel to do that.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov How do you figure? Also, as an aside, both the `sync()` Linux system call and `sync` GNU coreutils program are guaranteed to flush everything that was in the cache at the time when they were called before returning (from `man 2 sync`: "Linux waits for I/O completions, and thus `sync()` or `syncfs()`  provide the same  guarantees as `fsync()` called on every file in the system or filesystem respectively."). The caveat about `sync()` merely scheduling the flush only applies to its formal POSIX specification.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.